# Bootstrap minified css only loads if I import it in index.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

So, I was using the BootstrapCDN loader up until now, but I would like to just download the files and use them locally without relying on my internet connection, but the styles won't load. I only need the **grid** by the way.

I am using reactjs with material ui and bootstrap's grid -> [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38NYz.jpg)

I changed the stylesheet link and script to point to my files and I also changed the jQuery and Popper.js tags accordingly.

**CSS**

from

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"...>`

to

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/bootstrap/sources/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

**JS**

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"`

now:

`<script src="../src/bootstrap/sources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

and the same thing with

`<script src="../src/bootstrap/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../src/bootstrap/popper.min.js"></script>`

while the link to `bootstrap.min.css` is in the `<header>` and all the others being in the `<body>` tag.

The grid doesn't work and everything is messed up. But if I include an `import './bootstrap/sources/css/bootstrap.min.css';` in my `/src/index.js` file - the file where I have my private routes to certain pages - the grid actually works.

If I changed it back to cash bootstrap's css from the BootstrapCDN and specify the link as it was before, I don't have to include that import and the grid works flawlessly.

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: chrome shows the css file and all the js file being loaded with **code 304** - not modified in the network tab

Comment: Can you show us folder structure in your project?

Comment: Ofc, sorry - I added a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: there's nothing wrong in keeping the CSS import in your JS file... what's wrong with it?
This is a common way to go in React.

About your specific issue: You are referring to a not existent file like `../src/bootstrap/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js`. This because this path is valid in your source, but not in the final bundle.

If you are using `create-react-app` for example, you should put your resources (the `bootstrap` folder) in the `public` folder instead, so the used URL should be something like `"/bootstrap/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"`.
Even better: use the `%PUBLIC_URL%` variable.

See https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder

Comment: I assumed bootstrap would be imported correctly if I added the path to `index.html` - except I was importing it wrong.

TIL. Thanks a lot!